# Changing array key from a number to a name

Tags: php, arrays, explode

I have a string that separates the values by line, so I used:

```
 $array = explode("\r\n", $string);
```

This separates the value up however it uses numbers for the key. Each value that is separated from the string is actually the key followed by the value i.e.. key=value. I want to replace the number in the array with what goes before the = in the value. So instead of:

```
 array (size=2)
     0 => string 'key1=value1' (Lenght=11)
     1 => string 'key2=value2' (Lenght=11)
```

I want:

```
 array (size=2)
     key1 => string 'value1' (Lenght=6)
     key2 => string 'value2' (Lenght=6)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe explode your values and use them in a new array, like so?

```
$array1 = array(
    'key1=value1', 'key2=value2'
);
$array2 = array();
foreach($array1 as $element) {
    $explodedElement = explode('=', $element);
    $array2[$explodedElement[0]] = $explodedElement[1];
}
```

EDIT:

To account for '=' characters within the values of your string, we should implode the exploded value with '=' after the first value of the exploded element, the first value will always be the key value, we assume. You should also account for spaces in the key, which is why we should trim the key and the imploded value.

```
$array1 = array(
    'url = url.com?id=123456', 'key2=value2'
);
$array2 = array();
foreach($array1 as $element) {
    $explodedElement = explode('=', $element);
    $array2[trim($explodedElement[0])] = trim(implode('=',array_slice($explodedElement, 1)));
}
```

Comment: If it solved your answer, please accept the answer :)

Comment: Hi, I did try but it said I had to wait a little longer... I think I spoke a little to soon though, kind of. Annoyingly some of the values also have equals in them. The string passes back a url and the url has an equals in it i.e. 'url' => string 'https://url.com?id=123456' any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Explode on '=', add this value with the corresponding key and remove the previous entry corresponding to this duet :

```
foreach ($array as $key => $arr) {
  $val = explode ('=', $arr);
  $array[$val[0]] = $val[1]; // Add key1 => string 'value1' (Lenght=6)
  unset ($array[$key]); // Remove 0 => string 'key1=value1' (Lenght=11)
}
```

Skip the unset part if you want to create a new array and keep the previous one obviously